# Fix image size in category blog layout

Tags: joomla-3.4, category-blog

How to crop and fix image in intro image on category blog layout?

[image: category blog layout]

and this is full image in full article like this

[image: full image]

Comment: Welcome to JSE. I'm not sure I understand what your issue is. Fix what exactly? The screenshots you've provided seem to be perfectly fine

Comment: To create symmetry images appear to be cropped, do you want the full image displayed?

Comment: yes  i want the full image displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **JImage** class for image manipulation:
https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JImage.html

Find an example in slide number 15
http://es.slideshare.net/nikosdion/hidden-in-plain-site-joomla-hidden-secrets-for-code-monkeys

To complement, see this article:
http://phproberto.com/es/36-create-thumbnails-on-the-fly-for-joomla-content-articles

Regards.